# How to mitigate security Problem when calling ProcessBuilder.command?

Tags: java, security, processbuilder

I want to call "openssl" on my linux command line for some decryption stuff.

When using

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("openssl", "enc", ...).start();
```

how can I be sure, that the actual openssl command is called?
Imagine an attacker who simply renames openssl -> openssl2 and adds his own evil program as "openssl" which in turn calls "openssl2" in the background but captures stdin and stdout and quietly dumps it in a secret file.

Is there any way to be sure, the correct OS program is called?

Thanks all!

Comment: if the system is already **that** compromised there is not much you can do...

Comment: What you could do is compare the executable against a hash you've already calculated before. The drawback is that on each update and system you will need to change this hash. as @luk2302 mentioned, if the attacker already penetrated the system, it's too late

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL and JNI

This way you will use your own library exemplar. Of course **it's still not safe if the system is compromised**, but this gives a small chance to remain intact

If you really need to use the openssl functionality, you can go the following way:
1. Go to here: https://www.openssl.org/source/
2. Compile openssl library for the desired (or multiple platforms).
3. Use JNI to call functions from the library.

Also you can find something useful here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/05/encryptiondecryption-invoking-openssl-through-jni-calls